# Спарсить все числа регулярным выражением

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

```
string str="3 5 8 2.14 33 / * + = e pi";
 regex regular("\b\d+[.,]?w*\b", regex_constants::icase);
 smatch result;
 regex_search(str,result,regular);
 while(regex_search(str, result, regular)) {
     cout << result.str() << " ";
     str = result.suffix();
 }
```

Почему не работает? Необходимо спарсить все числа.

Comment: В вашем шаблоне `\b` - это BACKSPACE, не цифра, обратный слеш перед `\d` исчезает, т.к. строковый литерал обычный, не raw, а `w*` находит 0+ букв `w` - в строке их нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для нахождения всех чисел можно воспользоваться следующим кодом:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::regex r(R"([-+]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?)");
    std::string s = "3 5 8 2.14 33 / * + = e pi";
    for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
                             i != std::sregex_iterator();
                             ++i)
    {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        std::cout << m.str() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[См. онлайн-демо](https://ideone.com/DXtLce)

**Подробности**:

- С помощью `std::sregex_iterator` можно получить все совпадения шаблона без модификации исходной строки
- Использование `R"(<шаблон>)"` позволяет избавиться от двойных обратных слешей (иначе необходимо использовать `\\d` вместо `\d`)

**Регулярное выражение**

- `[-+]?` - плюс или минус, опционально
- `\d*` - 0 и более цифр
- `\.?` - 1 или 0 точек, опционально
- `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
- `(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?` - 1 или 0 последовательностей след. шаблонов:

  - `[eE]` - `e` или `E`
  - `[-+]?` - плюс или минус, опционально
  - `\d+` - 1 и более цифр.

Comment: Тут можно посмотреть [демо регулярки](https://regex101.com/r/4hhdA0/1).