# Не работает регулярное выражение поиска цифр

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Имеется такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
  std::string sample_text = "just a few words and some 1 digits 2";
  std::regex expr("\\d", std::regex_constants::ECMAScript);
  std::smatch result;
  if (!std::regex_match(sample_text, result, expr)) {
    std::cout << "Text doesn't includes digits :(\n";
    return 0;
  }
  std::cout << "Text includes digits!\n";
  std::cout << "Digits: ";
  for (const auto& digit : result) {
    std::cout << digit << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

При проверке `std::regex_match` возвращает `false`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить доступ более чем к одной подстроке, найденной smatch()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736374/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-smatch) или [Спарсить все числа регулярным выражением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648119)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у вас не только цифра. `regex_match` - это соответствие выражению.

Попробуйте вместо него *поиск* - `regex_search`.

*Update*
Как вариант поиска всех вхождений:

```
int main()
{
    string sample_text = "just a few words and some 1 digits 2";
    regex expr("\\d", regex_constants::ECMAScript);

    auto dig_begin = sregex_iterator(sample_text.begin(), sample_text.end(), expr);
    auto dig_end   = sregex_iterator();

    cout << "Found " << distance(dig_begin, dig_end) << " digits:\n";

    for (sregex_iterator i = dig_begin; i != dig_end; ++i)
    {
        smatch match = *i;
        string match_str = match.str();
        cout << match_str << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, функция работает, но находит только цифру 1

Answer (score 0):

На всякий случай. Подобная программа с [традиционными регэкспами](https://linux.die.net/man/3/regcomp) не намного длиннее.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  const char *pattern = "[[:digit:]]";
  char *str = av[1] ? av[1] : (char *)"just a few words and some 1 digits 2";
  puts(str);

  regex_t reg;
  regcomp(&reg, pattern, REG_EXTENDED);
  regmatch_t match[1]; // for whole regexp match boundaries
  int ofs = 0;

  while (regexec(&reg, str + ofs, 1, match, 0) == 0) {
    int pos = match[0].rm_so + ofs;
    printf("found digit '%c' at pos %d\n", str[pos], pos);
    ofs += match[0].rm_eo; // or ofs = pos + 1; for one digit matching
  }

  return ofs ? (puts("End") == EOF) : (puts("NO MATCH"), 1);
}
```

P.S.
*с++ компилятор вполне принимает ее за свою*