# Регулярное выражение пропускает подстроку, если она включает символ ранее найденного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо найти в строке выражение: пробел, число, пробел. Использую следующее регулярное выражение: `[\s][0-9,.\-\/]+[\s]|[\s][0-9,.-\/]+$|^[0-9,.-\/]+[\s]`. При проверке получается следующее: если одно подходящее выражение было найдено, то следующее пропускается, т.к., видимо, поиск продолжается с места остановки, поэтому нет возможности увидеть ранее найденный пробел.

Есть идеи, что можно изменить, чтобы в строке `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` были выделены все числа, причем строки типа `Аполлон-1` не должны подходить под введенное правило?

В коде использую php функцию `preg_match_all`, которая выдает такой же результат, как и сайт regex101

[image: ex 1]

[image: ex 2]

Comment: (?<=\s)\d+(?=\s)

Comment: @splash58 , точно, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблон для поиска всех чисел уже известен, это `[-+]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?`, см. [Спарсить все числа регулярным выражением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648119).

Вам остаётся лишь добавить `(?<!\S)` (блок предварительного просмотра назад, ищет пробельный символ или начало строки) слева и `(?!\S)` (блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, ищет пробельный символ или конец строки) справа.

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/2tW3vG/1).

[PHP-демо](https://3v4l.org/t7qMI):

```
$str = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Apollo-1 10';
if (preg_match_all('/(?<!\S)[-+]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?(?!\S)/', $str, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
)
```